# How to use linq-to-typescript orderby function with integers

Tags: typescript

I have an array of players each of which has a shirt number and I would like to return these in shirt number order (normally 1-11).

I am using the linq-to-typescript library.

I tried

```
 return from(this.team.players)
  .orderBy(p => p.shirtNumber)
  .toArray();
```

but it returns players in the order 1,10, 11, 2,3,4.... which looks to me like a string comparison is being performed.  This is despite shirtnumber being defined as `number`

Comment: did you use [Blinq](https://github.com/biggyspender/blinq/).

Comment: Check the github issues of the package you are using. [this one](https://github.com/arogozine/LinqToTypeScript/issues/19). Marked as "enchancement". so not implemented as i believe and uses default alphabetical comparer as plain js Array.sort.

Comment: @SergeySosunov - thanks for that I now have a solution : `.orderBy<number>(p => p.shirtNumber, NumberComparer)` does the trick

Comment: @UğurDemirel - I have not tried blinq.  linq-to-typescript seems adequate for my needs

Answer (score 2):

The answer was simple if a little tricky to find.  Sergey's comment above led me the answer, now it seems obvious.

```
return from(this.team.players)
  .orderBy<number>(p => p.shirtNumber, NumberComparer)
  .ToArray();
```